# Page application + Autolayout + Subviews scale while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've been working on a controller for 4 days and i can't fix my problems!

Let met explain my architecture :

I have a "Rootview", wich contains a ScrollView and anImageView (Both of them added in IB)

Then I have 4 external view controllers.

What I want is : Position my 4 viewcontrollers in my scrollview (this works fine, both of the views are added in my scrollView in code) and allow the users to scroll between the views

When I scroll i have a little animation that scales my views to 50% and then re-scale them to 100%.

When I disable "Autolayout" in IB everything works great ! My animation and the position of my views.
But, i can't disable it beacause I want my app working on iPhone4 and iPhone5.

I don't know how to implement my constraints to positions correctly all my views.
I juste want my views to be resize 50 pixels in height to fit on an iPhone 4 screen.

There's my scrollViewConfiguration

```
- (void)configureScrollView{
/* On déclare le nombre de page la scrollview */
if (self.myCurrentEvent.isEvent)
{
    self.numberOfScrollViewPages = 2;
}
else
{
    self.numberOfScrollViewPages = 4;
}

/* On initialise le tableau qui va contenir les tableviews */
viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

/* Tant qu'on a pas atteint le nombre de pages de la scrollview */
for (unsigned i = 0; i < self.numberOfScrollViewPages; i++)
{
    /* On ajoute NSNull au tableau de tableview */
    [self.viewControllersArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

[self.myScrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

/* On configure la content size en prenant la taille de la scroll view x le nombre de pages */
self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.myScrollView.frame.size.width * self.numberOfScrollViewPages, self.myScrollView.frame.size.height);

/* On désactive l'affichage du scroll horizontal */
self.myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

/* On désactive l'affichage du scroll vertical */
self.myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

/* On désactive la fonction scroll to top */
self.myScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;

/* On indique implémenter les fonction du son delegate */
self.myScrollView.delegate = self;

/* On affiche la première page */
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];

/* On affiche la deuxième page */
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];

if (!self.myCurrentEvent.isEvent)
{
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:2];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:3];
}}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page{
/* Si la page passée en paramètre est inférieure à 0, on sort de la fonction */
if (page < 0) return;

/* Si la page passée en paramètre est supérieur au nombre de page de la scrollview */
if (page >= self.numberOfScrollViewPages) return;

/* On récupère la référence vers la view contenu dans le tableau des tableview */
UIViewController *aViewController = [self.viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:page];

/* Si la vue récupérée est nulle */
if ((NSNull *)aViewController == [NSNull null])
{
    switch (page)
    {
        case 0:
            [self configureEventDescriptionViewController];
            [self.viewControllersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:self.myEventDescriptionViewController];
            aViewController = self.myEventDescriptionViewController;
            break;

        case 1:
            [self configureListOfContactViewController];
            [self.viewControllersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:self.myListOfContactViewController];
            aViewController = self.myListOfContactViewController;
            break;

        case 2:
            [self configureListOfExpensesCategoryViewController];
            [self.viewControllersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:self.myListOfExpensesCategoryViewController];
            aViewController = self.myListOfExpensesCategoryViewController;
            break;

        case 3:
            [self configureLinkContactViewController];
            [self.viewControllersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:self.myLinkContactViewController];
            aViewController = self.myLinkContactViewController;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/* Si la superview de la vue est à nil */
if (aViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    [aViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.height = self.myScrollView.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.width = 320;
    frame.origin.x = page * 320;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [aViewController.view setFrame:frame];

    /* On ajoute la vue courante à la scrollview */
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
}

aViewController = nil;}
```

The part where i set the frame of a viewController frame works only if I disable autolayout

I hope you've undersatand what i wanted to say...

Sorry for my bad english...

Pwyll

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you could have two storyboards, one for 4 and one for 5. In app delegate interrogate the device screen size and load the appropriate storyboard in.

Again its not the best solution but you can also use .xib to make it work. I had to do this as I couldn't get my head around the constraints.

Comment: Yes... But i have around 15 .xib... i don't wanna use this solution for ALL my .xib :(